# How to securely obtain/store API credentials in a Unity game?

Tags: node.js, rest, unity-game-engine

I have created a global leaderboards API with node.js and I'm trying to integrate with a game created in Unity.  The leaderboards require authentication via username/pw and then use JWT tokens to secure the API.  I have a single username/pw combo for the game itself, so the game will first "login" to the API and then use the web token to make requests (post scores and retrieve them).

What I'm trying to figure out is how or where to store this login and pw. I'm apprehensive about hard coding it, because I don't want players to get locked out if I need to change it.  I should note that this user has limited access, but I still wouldn't want a malicious person to discover it since they can use it to post scores, so they could for example flood the leaderboards with bogus or inappropriate data.